# image doesn't change - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to change an image on runtime but it's not working.
I have a user control that when you click on imagebtn it's opening a new window with a list of images.
the next step is to take the image selected from the list, close the new window, and put the image on the imagebtn.
the user control still opens in the background.
this is my code.

NewWindow:

```
    private string myData;
    public ImagesWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitialImageList();
    }
   

    private async void InitialImageList()
    {
        //add try catch
        string get = await HttpRequests.GetRequest(URLImages);
        allJsonCategory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ImageArray>>(get);
        Console.WriteLine(get);
        ImageBoxList.ItemsSource = images;
        foreach (var item in allJsonCategory)
        {
            images.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void ImageBoxList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedImage = (ImageArray)ImageBoxList.SelectedItem;
        myData = selectedImage.full_path;
        Console.WriteLine("you clicked on: " + selectedImage.name);
        ProductsCategory pro = new ProductsCategory();
        pro.imagePath = myData;
        this.Close();
    }
```

my usercontrol(in mainWindow):

```
   public void setImage(string imagePath)
    {
        if (!imageURL.Equals(""))
        {
            Image imageBtn = new Image();

            var imgUrl = new Uri(imagePath);
            var imageData = new WebClient().DownloadData(imgUrl);

            // or you can download it Async won't block your UI
            // var imageData = await new WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync(imgUrl);

            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage { CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad };
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageData);
            bitmapImage.EndInit();

            imageBtn.Source = bitmapImage;

            //this.imageBtn.InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }
```

XAML of the image:

where is my mistake?

thank you all :)

Comment: `new ProductsCategory()` - so you set the image path in a newly created (and then discarded) instance instead of in the existing instance.

Comment: how can i send the imagepath to the user control ?

Comment: You need a reference to the existing control. So either make this available to the ImagesWindow instance, or - better - let ImagesWindow inform the main window about the new image selection (e.g. via an event) and do this in the main window

Comment: Why you cast imageboxlist.selecteditem to imagearray?

Comment: because the list item is a imagearray object. and the image selected show only the image but there are more element like name etc..

Comment: Can you show me please how to do that?